# Minimizing Window all the contents get squished

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner at HTML and CSS. When I try to minimize my window the contents on the footer is stacking on top of each other. Also when I minimize moving the bottom to the top the footer is also pushed to the top.

Below are the links to the html, and css

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Samuel Selvarajah</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Logo.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-responsive...

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "container">
        <div id = "menu-bar">
            <img src = "Logo1.ico"/>
            <ul>
                <li> about </li>
                <li> projects </li>
                <li> resume </li>
                <li> contact </li>
            </ul>
            <p id = "linkin"><strong> in </strong></p>
            <p id = "facebook"><strong> f </strong></p>
            <img id = "github" src = "25231.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id = "footer">
            <ul>
                <li> about </li>
                <li> projects </li>
                <li> resume </li>
                <li> contact </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>

</html> 



body{
background-image: url("hp.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
overflow:auto;
}

.container{
width: 700px;
height: 700px;
}

#menu-bar{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 85px;
background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5qGr.png");    
}

div img{
position: fixed;
zoom: 30%;
top: 10px;
left: 350px;
}

#menu-bar ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px; 
position: relative;
left: 400px;
top: 30px;
}

#menu-bar li{
display: inline;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 26px;
color: white;
}

#linkin{
position: fixed;
margin: 0px;
padding:0px;
font-family: Segoe UI, Myriad Pro, Myriad, Liberation Sans, Nimbus Sans L,    Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: white;
top: 28px;
left: 1130px;
font-size: 33px;
}

#facebook{
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
padding:0px;
font-family: Segoe UI, Myriad Pro, Myriad, Liberation Sans, Nimbus Sans L,   Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: white;
top: 8px;
left: 1040px;
font-size: 33px;
}

#github{
position: fixed;
left: 7180px;
zoom: 15%;
top: 150px;
}

#footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: -200px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 39px;
background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5qGr.png");

}

#footer ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px; 
bottom: 10px;
left: 435px;
position: absolute;
}

#footer li{
display: inline;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
padding: 18px;
font-size: 16px;
position: relative;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: There is space in the last CSS `bootstrap-      responsive.css`, it shouldn't be

Comment: Where is the css that is styling this html?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute/Fixed positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Try [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/oent5s8f/5/).

It needs a lot of improvements but it will get you started.

Also try not to use IDs (#) in your css.

[Further reading](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/).

```
.content {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
.logo {
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
}
.menu-bar{
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5qGr.png");
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%; 
}
.menu-bar li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    padding: 15px;
}
.footer {
    background: #ededed;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px -0.8px 0px #c6c6c6;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: i tried changing it with the properties that you have added, and all the contents are scrambled around.

Comment: It should work fine. Make sure that there are no spelling mistakes and that every tag has a closing tag.

Comment: just to test it I copied the html and css from the jsFiddle and it was all scrambled, and the problem wasnt really fixed. Even if you look at the output on the jFiddle site if you minimize the contents get stacked on top of each other.

Comment: I assume you added the missing tags? i.e. `<!DOCTYPE html>` `html` and also the link to your css file.

Comment: I added those the footer keeps moving up as I minimize from bottom to top. With the code I had the contents from the header weren't stacking on top of each other when I minimized. I think because I used a container, but when I tried using it for the footer it didnt work.

Comment: Alright so one issue is fixed. So now when I minimize from bottom to top the footer doesnt follow which is good. Do you think you can explain what the exact problem was that caused this to happen, what property that you added?

Comment: I removed `position: absolute;` from `.footer`. An element that has absolute position is removed from the flow of elements on the page and is not affected by other elements.